# Multi gateway routing in ubuntu

Tags: networking, ip, routing, traceroute

I want to setup Multi gateway on my Ubuntu Machine. 1 for ethernet and another for USB tethering. After browsing, from the below reference

https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System

I have configured my system according to that.

Configuration :

1. Ethernet as my default route
2. USB is configured through iproute2, taken reference from above mentioned site

Issue is I am unable to ping through USB interface.

```
$ ping -I usb0 www.google.co.in
PING www.google.co.in (173.194.117.88) from 192.168.42.122 usb0: 56(84) bytes of data.
icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

But traceroute is not able to show the gateway correctly for both USB

```
$ traceroute -i usb0 173.194.117.88
traceroute to 173.194.117.88 (173.194.117.88), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1 192.168.200.254 (192.168.200.254)  1.956 ms  2.817 ms *
2 * * *
3 * * *


$ traceroute -i eth0 173.194.117.88
traceroute to 173.194.117.88 (173.194.117.88), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  192.168.200.254 (192.168.200.254)  2.020 ms  2.870 ms  3.568 ms
2  10.251.0.1 (10.251.0.1)  21.041 ms  21.437 ms  21.988 ms
```

**Routing Information**

```
$ ip rou
default via 192.168.200.254 dev eth0  proto static 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.42.122      metric 1 
192.168.200.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.200.102    metric 1

$ ip route list table usbrt
default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0  scope link  src 192.168.42.122 

$ ip route list table usbrt
default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0  scope link  src 192.168.42.122 

$ ip -4 addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
 inet 192.168.200.102/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global eth0
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
inet 192.168.42.122/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global usb0


$ ip rule show
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from all to 192.168.42.122 lookup usbrt 
32765:  from 192.168.42.122 lookup usbrt 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Comment: Please add both routing tables and the output of `ip -4 addr show` to your question by [editing](http://askubuntu.com/posts/679540/edit) it.

Comment: I have updated, please have a look into it,

Comment: Routing tables look fine. Did you add the proper rules, e.g `ip rule add from 192.168.42.122/32 table usbrt`. What's the output of `ip rules show`?

Comment: please find the output for   $ ip rule show in above edited "Routing Information".  Regarding $ ip rule add. I used the same mentioned command by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer.
use "Interface_IP" instead of "Interface_name" in ping
**example :**
use

```
ping -i 192.168.42.122 www.google.co.in
```

instead of

```
ping -i eth0 www.google.co.in
```